# iOS UISlider not moving when I swipe, even though other UI elements are fine

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xib, uislider

I've created a simple xib file with three buttons and a UISlider.

When I start the app on my phone I'm able to tap the buttons no problem, but the UISlider is locked and doesn't move..

However if I keep trying to move it with my finger it eventually scrolls left and right fine, but only after about a minute of furious screen swiping..

I thought it might be because it was hidden behind something onscreen (not that there's anything for it to hide behind) so I did 'arrange -> send to front', but this doesn't help.

Does anyone know why it might be doing this?

Comment: Do you do any custom logic in the value changed handler for the slider? Could it be that it gets disabled in the code after a small change in value, so it looks like it never moves at all?

Comment: Aah I figured out - my screen was set to Retina which confused the xib - it thought the slider location was further down the screen, even though it was drawing it in a different place..